# In C++/CLI, how to copy a char * to a System::String (not a C++ std::string)?

Tags: string, char, c++-cli

Though I know C well, I'm having trouble with copying a char array to a `System::String` (not a C++ `std::string`) in C++/CLI.

I'm using (for the first time) Visual Studio with its drop-and-drag form design feature to create a C++ Windows GUI program.  The program works mostly, but I'm having trouble copying a char array (created with `sprintf`) to a `System::String` (the type used by many of the Visual Studio controls).

I tried writing this function:

```
private: System::String^ cts(char *aa) {  // convert char[] to String

    int i;
    String^ s;

    s = "";
    for (i = 0; aa[i]; i++)
        s = s + aa[i];
    return s;
}
```

But cts("h") returns "104" (the ASCII code for lower case h), and I want it to return "h" in String format.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please make sure you understand exactly what language you are using, as well as any third-party libraries. The C++ standard library does not have a `System` namespace, and `^` is not part of the syntax for types. My **guess** is that you are using [this thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI), which is **not** C++.

Comment: "I'm using (for the first time) Visual Studio with its drop-and-drag form design feature to create a C++ Windows GUI program." Okay; but what does that have to do with the **question you are asking**? Please read [ask], and try to keep background information focused on *what is needed in order to understand the problem*. Also, make sure to **ask a question**; "Help would be appreciated" [does not qualify](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236).

Comment: Thanks, Karl.  Yes, I didn't know I was using C++/CLI, which I had not heard of, and chose it by watching a YouTube video about creating a Visual Studio project.  But that explains the constructs that I didn't recognize, as my last (just one) C++ effort was many years ago, my main experience being C programming. Regarding "using Visual Studio for the first time", I wrote that so readers would understand that the environment and the syntax were new to me, though I could have more brief. As for "Help would be appreciated", it seemed a polite addition, but I'll avoid it in future questions.

Comment: It's nice to be polite, but we like directness, and we like *explicit questions*. Such as "How can I get XYZ result?" or "Why do I get ABC result instead of the expected XYZ?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**`System::String`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/extensions/string-cpp-component-extensions?view=msvc-170) has a constructor that accepts a `const char*`.
Therefore all you have to do is to use `gcnew` to create a new `System::String` passing the `const char*` as a parameter (a `char*` can also be passed).

See the code below:

```
System::String^ cts(const char *aa)
{
    return gcnew System::String(aa);
}

int main()
{
    System::String ^ system_str = cts("abcd");
    System::Console::WriteLine(system_str);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
abcd
```